# How to insert multi-dimension arrays in mysql using codigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am beginner to this field. How to insert the multi-dimension array values in two columns. That is stu_ans_id, and stu_answer. The array output example below:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [stu_ans_id] => 1
            [stu_answer] => Hello
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [stu_ans_id] => 2
            [stu_answer] => True
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [stu_ans_id] => 4
            [stu_answer] => A
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [stu_ans_id] => 6
            [stu_answer] => Hii
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [stu_ans_id] => 7
            [stu_answer] => Array
                (
                    [1] => A
                    [2] => B
                    [3] => C
                )

        )

)
```

Its my controller

```
 public function add_stu_ans()
  {

          $id = $values['stu_ans_id'] = $this->input->post('qstn_id');
          $ans =  $values['stu_answer']  =  $this->input->post('ans'); 

          $testArr=array_combine($id,$ans);
          $arr=[];

          foreach ($testArr as $key => $value) 
          {
            $arr[]=array('stu_ans_id'=>$key,'stu_answer'=>$value);
          }


            $this->Common_model->insert_answer('student',$arr);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message_name' , 'Your Data is Inserted');
            redirect('Quiz/tot_marks');

  }
```

And its my model

```
public function insert_answer($table, $arr)
        {

            $result = $this->db->insert_batch($table, $arr);
            return $this->db->affected_rows();

        }
```

Anyone please help me to solve this issue

> The first 4 array gets a input textbox, radio button values but that last array is get a checkbox value. so this cause complicate to me.

Comment: you could do a json_encode of stu_answer and store that string in the db, for each stu_answer. When you retrieve the data just do a json_decode

Comment: Mam actually I am new to this coding. I have so many doubts so please give your gmail id. for learning purpose.

Comment: can you please show us your code?

Comment: @DarshanDave sir i edited, please check it.

Comment: `$arr[]=array('stu_ans_id'=>$key,'stu_answer'=>is_array($value) ? json_encode($value) : $value);`

Comment: can you provide DB table schema where you insert this data?